# My web site not found & Firefox hangs. Any ideas?

Tags: nginx, websites

On Ubuntu 22.04 using nginx, curl rose-server.duckdns.org hangs, as does rose-server.duckdns.org in Firefox. nginx is shown as active(running) by sudo service nginx status nginx. I can ping rose-server.duckdns.org Ok.

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/rose-server.duckdns.org` has link to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/rose-server.duckdns.org`. certbot setup Ok for rose-server.duckdns.org.

I have certbot setup.

Comment: Your server seems up and running at IP address `92.24.27.85`, and the URL `http://92.24.27.85/` works, too.

Comment: Works for me too.

Comment: Weird. Could this be because I'm accessing the website on the same computer as I created it?